# Regarding a property of the Kronecker Delta

Tags: kronecker-delta

I would like to know how this property of the Kronecker delta works. How exactly is $\delta_{a1}\delta_{1c} + \delta_{a2}\delta_{2c} + \delta_{a3}\delta_{3c} = \delta_{ac}$?

[Two deltas reduced to one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3aX7.png)

Comment: Is it known that $a,c$ must be one of $1,2,3$?

Comment: Use the definition. What is $\delta_{a1}$ equal to? What is the value of the product $\delta_{a1}\delta_{1c}$?

Comment: Wherever I look, this property is given without any proof, like in the picture. It isn't specified if a and c are (1,2 or 3), it is just said that one sums over the same indices. In this case b (see the picture).

Comment: @pegasus how can delta(a1)delta(1c) have a value if we don't know what a and c are?

Comment: @ali_runnindis, notice that the final expression depends on $a$ and $c$. Try to calculate the expression for each of the (9) possible combinations of $a$ and $c$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you